# Getting error "cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port" when calling API from another container

Tags: php, node.js, docker

I am dockerizing an app that has several different services and I have used the Docker Compose file to achieve this Single docker-compose.yml file for all the services and one Dockerfile for each service.

1. Frontend(angular)[http://localhost:4200]
2. Backend(PHP)[http://localhost:80]
3. Backend Database(Mysql)
4. Integration Service(NodeJS)[http://localhost:4433]
5. Integration Service Database(MongoDB)
6. Authentication Layer(NodeJS)[http://localhost:4454]
7. Authentication Layer Database(Mysql)

So far I have successfully containerized all these services but when my "Backend(PHP)" container tries to call API from "Integration Service(NodeJS)" it throws the error which is `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 4433: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`.

```
services:
  angular-service:
    container_name: wms_frontend
    build: ../frontend/.
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
  php:
    build: 
      context: .
    image: wms-backend
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=wms-backend-mysql-app
      - MYSQL_USER=wmsroot
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DB=dbname
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/wms/backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    container_name: wms-backend-php-app
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - MYSQL_USER=wmsroot
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=
    volumes:
      - ./dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    container_name: wms-backend-mysql-app
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.7
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "40002:80"
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=wms-backend-mysql-app
      - PMA_PORT= 3306
    volumes:
      - /sessions
    container_name: wms-backend-phpmyadmin-app
  app:
    container_name: wms_auth
    restart: always
    build: ../../wms_auth/.
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ../../auth/./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4454:4454"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD= YES
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=auth
      - MYSQL_USER= root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
      - ../../auth/dump/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysql", "-h", "db","-u","root", "mysql", "-e", "select 1"]
      interval: 1s
      retries: 20
  wms_integration:
    container_name: integration
    restart: always
    build: ../../wmsIntegeration/.
    volumes:
      - ../../wmsIntegeration/./:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "4433:4433"
    networks:
      - backend
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
  wms_integration_db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "27019:27017"
    volumes:
      - ../../wmsIntegeration/mongodb:/data/db
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo db:27017/config --quiet
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
    
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Comment: You might want to add a link to the integration service so that you can access it internally between containers.

Comment: how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not access the other container using the container name, or any self-chosen alias? Also, is this really a problem of Node when the PHP code (which you forgot to share) throws such an error?

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means "this container"; you can't use it to connect between containers.  You can use the Compose service name as a host name, as @NicoHaase suggests; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for more details.  (The various `links:` and `networks:` settings are just confusing things and I'd suggest deleting them all.)

Comment: i have also tried to use the container name as localhost but then it says "Could not resolve host: CONTAINER_NAME"

Answer (score -1):

Bridge all the networks as follows :

```
networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
  frontend: 
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The `bridge` driver is usually the default, unless you're deploying to Docker's Swarm clustering system, in which case you probably actually want the default `overlay`.  I don't think this helps solve the problem in the question.